# Why does the ObjectStateManager property not exist in my db context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to return a list of newly added objects from my database context.

I have read that i have to use `ObjectStateManager` for this purpos. The problem is, that my database context does not have the `ObjectStateManager` property.

The context works fine for retrivieing, adding and updating objects though.

I am using EF 5.0

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

What can i do?

Comment: "I have to use ObjectStateManager for this." -- As you've seen, `ObjectStateManager` does still work, but you don't need it. `DbContext`-derived classes can use the [`ChangeTracker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker(v=vs.103).aspx) property to get that information.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try this:

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```

Comment: IObjectContextAdapter not found in netcore?

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: It's not exactly the answer but helped me solving a problem