# Entity Framework Update when there's an Id value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, poco

The short question is, can I make EF perform an update when the Poco class has a value for the primary key field and an insert otherwise?  Exactly the way NHibernate does.

Unless I'm mistaken the EF way is really ugly.

First instead of using .Add(entity) for inserts or updates you .Add for inserts and for updates:

```
context.MyEntities.Attach(entity);
```

I tried that but nothing was saved at all. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581473/why-does-the-objectstatemanager-property-not-exist-in-my-db-context) I saw I was missing setting the changed state?  But my context doesn't have an ObjectStateManager so I need something like:

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```

This seems like a very convoluted and inelegant approach to me.  Can I make EF work the way NHibernate does?  (If not I'm still early enough in the project that I can rip EF out and go back to using NHibernate)

Comment: It sounds like you have much more expertise with nHibernate and that you are free to choose which ORM to use, so why not use it?

Comment: To expand on my comment: I don't mean to be flippant. I mean, the two products accomplish the same thing in different ways. I suspect that you will find many instances of being frustrated with the differences as you continue to implement your project.

Comment: That's a good point and exactly the question I'm now asking myself.  I tried EF to see what it had to offer.  I like the VS power tools. I can't understand this approach regarding insert/update it seems like it would result in more code being written to plumb values across.  Especially when using ASP.NET MVC which autopopulates your Poco entities from the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the context.Add(entity) in order for Entity Framework to know that it needs to track changes on that object. If the entity already exists in the context, EF will automatically track changes to it and push those changes to the database when you call context.SaveChanges().

Comment: So the approach would be to find the entity first then copy across all fields from my UI to the "found entity" then call SaveChanges?

Comment: In theory, you should be tightly bound to your entities, so that the UI changes are updating the values on your entities. If that's the case, all you have to do is validate and save changes. If you are loosely bound, then you need to write the changes from the UI to your "found entity" and then save changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching an entity so you should try EntityState = Modified before savechanges.