# Entity Framework C# - ObjectStateManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am finding very hard to find a solution to this problem. I have created an Edit.cshtml view in my MVC application. Currently in my Controller I have the following code

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Vendor vendor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Vendors.Attach(vendor);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(vendor, EntityState.Modified);  
            db.Entry(vendor).CurrentValues.SetValues(vendor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vendor);
    }
```

But before i build the "dbo.ObjectStateManager" gives my an Error. As below!

> Error 25  'VendorScorecard.Models.VendorScorecardEntities1' does not contain a definition for 'ObjectStateManager' and no extension method 'ObjectStateManager' accepting a first argument of type 'VendorScorecard.Models.VendorScorecardEntities1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\solutions\Web\VisualStudio2010\VendorScorecard\VendorScorecard-Good\VendorScorecard\Controllers\VendorController.cs  90  20  VendorScorecard

i have tried thid line of code too! It removes the error but doesnt actually allow intput into my database

> //db.Entry(vendor).State = EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score 2):

From: [Why does the ObjectStateManager property not exist in my db context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581473/why-does-the-objectstatemanager-property-not-exist-in-my-db-context)

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will resolve your problem

```
db.Entry(employeeFromDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

so basically you have to get rid of one line and put this code instead please see below

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Vendor vendor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Vendors.Attach(vendor);
             db.Entry(vendor).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(vendor).CurrentValues.SetValues(vendor);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vendor);
    }
```