# ObjectStateManager no definition issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing problem with `ObjectStateManager`.

I am `using` both `System.Data.Entity` and `System.Data.Objects` however it shows no definition for `ObjectStateManager`.

```
SampleContext db = new SampleContext();
Employees employeeFromDB = db.Employees.Single(x => x.Id == employee.Id);

employeeFromDB.FullName = employee.FullName;
employeeFromDB.Gender = employee.Gender;
employeeFromDB.Age = employee.Age;
employeeFromDB.HireDate = employee.HireDate;
employeeFromDB.Salary = employee.Salary;
employeeFromDB.PersonalWebSite = employee.PersonalWebSite;

db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(employeeFromDB, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Details", new {Id = employee.Id});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Why does the ObjectStateManager property not exist in my db context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581473/why-does-the-objectstatemanager-property-not-exist-in-my-db-context)

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```

Comment: you have to use your dbcontext object

Comment: Accept answers if your issue is resolved to help others !!

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
db.Entry(employeeFromDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
//db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(employeeFromDB,System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
db.SaveChanges();
```