# Unable to cast object of type 'DBContext.Models.Contact' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I am trying to implement "Repository-Pattern" and "Edit" method in Contact-Controller is making use of "Attach Method" in Contact-Repository is throwing Error.

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Contacts.Models.Contact' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'.
```

Before This issue i faced another issue of  ObjectStateManger Extension not found error in the code :

```
entities.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
```

So i had to use new variable "manager" as a solution for the issue from another stack over flow thread ([ObjectStateManager no definition issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653043/objectstatemanager-no-definition-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1))
Attach Method in Contact-Repository

```
public void Attach(Contact entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

           var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)entity).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;

            entities.Contacts.Attach(entity);

           manager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);

        }
```

Edit Method in Contact Controller that makes use of ContactRespository

```
public ActionResult Edit(int?id)
            {
                Contact contact = repo.Get(c => c.ID == id);
                if (contact == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(contact);
            }


            //
            // POST: /Contacts/Edit/5

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    repo.Attach(contact);
                    repo.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(contact);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653043/objectstatemanager-no-definition-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1) you have referenced, the answer has this:

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
                                      ^^
                                      ||
                                   see this is db
```

That works because the OP in that question has a type which implements the `IObjectContextAdapter`. The OP in that question has this:

```
SampleContext db = new SampleContext();
```

You are trying to do this:

```
var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)entity).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;
```

Your `entity` does not implement that interface so you cannot cast it to `IObjectContextAdapter` and that is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I Replaced the Entire Attach Code with this line and its working.

            `entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;`
Even in my  code i have 
       ` private CTEntities entities = new CTEntities();`

And i replaced 
           `var manager = ((IObjectContextAdapter)entities).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager;`

I replaced entity with "Entities" which was the instance of my DBContext and its working fine. Thank You very Much!