# Exception in EF Core return multiple results with stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core for getting multiple results from a SQL Server database via a stored procedure.

This is my code:

```
var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
connection.Open();

var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "EXEC [dbo].[GetUserById] @Id='" + id + "'";

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var usersFromMultiple = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<List<UserModel>>(reader);
```

I get this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type UserDbContext to type 'system.data.entity.infrastructure.iobjectcontextadapter'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to cast object of type 'DBContext.Models.Contact' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282986/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-dbcontext-models-contact-to-type-system-data-en)

Comment: does UserDbContext inherit DbContext?

Comment: There is no `IObjectContextAdapter` (and `ObjectContext` etc.) in EF Core. Are you mixing EF Core with EF6 code?

Comment: Yes. There is some other way to handle multiple results from store procedure?

Comment: Well, using EF core to execute a stored procedure and return an entity or list of entities provided they are mapped to the DbContext you can simply call the `.FromSql()` extension - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql. Though this does have a bunch of limitations as listed on the page linked

Comment: @liolrn Not yet. There is an open issue for this [Support multiple resultsets #8127](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8127), you can try the workaround by ppn2.